# Unable to append append 0 in column value if value does not have a decimal point

Tags: oracle

I am generating a file from Oracle table where one of the column is of NUMBER data type.

The column definition is:

```
Amount NUMBER(13,2)
```

In this column, I have data out of which some with decimal point and some does not.

```
e.g

1234.45
1245
1234.23
```

While getting the data, in case for values without having decimal point, I want the data to be appended with `00` (*as scale is 2*). For values with decimal it should be as it is.

```
e.g.

1234.45
1245.00
1234.23
```

How can I do that?

I can not simply pad with `0` as it is condition based. I am getting stuck at a point where I am not able to identify how to append `0s` if there is a decimal point.

Comment: This is something which might best be handled in your presentation layer.  Are you asking how to generate this particular output in SQL developer?

Comment: Yes, It needs to be handled in SQL query itself. My application is a back end app and it just writes the fetched data into a file. So if the data is appearing as 1245, its getting written as 12.45.

Comment: The edit by @Community is vandalism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it to characters and use the `FM999999999.00` formatter:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(your_column, 'FM999999999.00') AS RES FROM DUAL
```

The `FM` which is Fill mode. Allows variable-length number of digit as a subset of the number of digit that is provided before the decimal in the mask, so 999999999 = 9 digits, 8 digits will also be tolerated. But it will not accept 10 digits before the decimal.

The `.00` represents the number of decimals after the point, in case you add more digits after the decimal, they will be rounded e.g. `100.246` ==> `100.25`.

Format Model Modifiers Reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#BABDAEDF

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *to_char(col_name,'9999.00')*

The 9s represent optional place holders.
The 0s represent putting in leading zeros.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!